# Delete sub document in nodejs with mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with a following data:

```
{
       "__v": NumberInt(0),
       "_id": ObjectId("565443b1172e19d51f98b0ed"),
       "address": "tohana",
       "comments": [
         {
           "_id": ObjectId("5654455fe088d89c20736e3c"),
           "comment": "good man",
           "uemail": "dinesh@gmail.com",
           "uname": "dinesh" 
        },
         {
           "_id": ObjectId("565445e471dce6ca20705a84"),
           "comment": "nice person",
           "uemail": "kr@gmail.com",
           "uname": "krishan" 
        },
         {
           "_id": ObjectId("5654460e7aa73bec2064060e"),
           "comment": "bad person",
           "uemail": "Rai",
           "uname": "Rahul" 
        } 
      ],
       "email": "nishantg@ocodewire.com"▼,
       "name": "Nishant" 
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how to remove a subdocument from a 'comments' key having only id of subdocument, I am going to del?
for instance i want to del a subdocument with id `5654455fe088d89c20736e3c` So this subdocument should be deleted.

Here is code i am using:

```
var Users = require("../app/models/users"); //userModel

app.post('/deleteComment/:id', function(req, res) {
    var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var id = req.params.id;//commentId
    var userId = input.id;//userId

    Users.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
      '$pull': {
        'comments':{ '_id': new ObjectId(someStringValue) }
       }
    });
});
```

But this does not delete data.

Comment: above mentioned JSON is a Post request body? Are you using mongoose wrapper for mongodb?

Comment: Okay. Perfect. First you have to get full document with id(document id not comment id) then remove comment from return document like you can use lodash or underscore to find and delete that comment from comment array. after doing this again save/update the new updated document. make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/deleteComment/:id', function(req, res) {
var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
var id = req.params.id;
var userId = input.uid;
 Users.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: userId}, 
        {$pull: {comments: {_id: id}}},
        function(err, data){
           if(err) return err;
           res.send({data:data});
    });
})
```